# Layer problems with youtube embed and button in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube

I'm using the YouTube embed API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference) to stream a YouTube clip inside a swf file. I have put a transparent button over the top of the YouTube clip but once it's loaded, the embedded clip keeps appearing over the button.

How can I change the layer order so that the button always stays at the top?

Here is my AS3 code to embed the YouTube clip…

```
// This will hold the API player instance once it is initialized.
var player:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();

var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com")
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/Z3wnzmJBCDo?version=3&rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
   // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the Player API ID
trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);

// Once this event has been dispatched by the player, we can use
// cueVideoById, loadVideoById, cueVideoByUrl and loadVideoByUrl
// to load a particular YouTube video.
player = loader.content;
// Set appropriate player dimensions for your application
player.setSize(300, 250);

}

function onPlayerError(event:Event):void {
// Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the error code
trace("player error:", Object(event).data);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
// Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new player state
trace("player state:", Object(event).data);
}

function onVideoPlaybackQualityChange(event:Event):void {
// Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new video quality
trace("video quality:", Object(event).data);
}
```

Thanks very much,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating two containers - one for your custom items and one for the youtube player.

```
var myLittleCustomContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
var youtubeContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(youtubeContainer);
addChild(myLittleCustomContainer);

...
function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    youtubeContainer.addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}
....
```

You can add your object whenever and wherever you want like this:

```
myLittleCustomContainer.addChild(YOUR_DISPLAY_OBJECT);
```

And it will be in front of the player

Comment: Thanks @KumoKairo _ i'm a little bit confused with the _YOUR_DISPLAY_OBJECT bit, what exactly do I need to put in there?

I'm not very experienced in AS3 so may need some guidance ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to make the loader object always stay in the bottom layer and anything  else above it?

Comment: @James Payne YOUR_DISPLAY_OBJECT is your button) Please provide the code where you add your button to the display list or just initializing your button

Comment: @James Payne "Is it possible to make the loader object always stay in the bottom layer and anything else above it" I've already done that in the code. You have two layers - two containers. Just look at the names of the variables

Comment: I have a button in the library with the name of btn_link and the linkage of ClickTagButton. I was putting the button straight onto the stage - do I not need to do this? Can I reference the button straight from the library? Here is my code so far…

Comment: @James Payne the easiest way to reference your button straight from the library. You should manually create a button from your custom class and add it as a child of your button container. Like this http://pastie.org/8293660

Comment: Brilliant stuff - I've added the button as child of the container and it's all now working :-)

Here's the finished code with the added Flash clickTAG code to track clicks in DFP - http://pastie.org/8293710

Thanks so much for your help @KumoKairo :-)